When building container in SAM it's getting stuck in building container?
When executing the sam build command, SAM generates a Docker container, but the process extends for 2-3 hours without completion.
However, upon removing snowflake-sqlalchemy from the requirements.txt file, the container builds successfully. Similarly, when incorporating snowflake-sqlalchemy into a new SAM application, the container builds(without other dependecies).
I've observed that the container utilizes 99-100% CPU, and the internet connection speed is optimal. Despite this, the container takes longer than usual to build.
Here are the dependencies listed for reference:
boto3
requests
snowflake-sqlalchemy
langchain
langchain-community
langchain-openai
pg8000
psycopg2-binary
pgvector
plotly
kaleido
llama-index-vector-stores-postgres
llama-index
llama-index-core
llama-index-agent-openai
llama-index-llms-openai
llama-index-embeddings-openai
llama-index-llms-anthropic
llama-index-vector-stores-astra-db
llama-index-experimental
llama-index-postprocessor-flag-embedding-reranker
llama-index-llms-anthropic
cryptography


SAM version : 1.118.0
Python version : 3.12


What is the version of SAM CLI in your machine?

I am currently using 1.114.0 version.

Could you try updating your sam cli to the latest version (1.118.0)?

I tried upgrading SAM cli but still it's not working.

Facing the same even with empty requirements

After reactivating docker daemon, it worked again to me
For more
How to run docker daemon?
